# How to upgrade from terrafrom 0.12 to 0.14?

Tags: terraform

I have to upgrade some terraform stacks from version 0.12 to 0.14.
What steps should I use?

I found this command: `terraform 0.13upgrade` which I can use to upgrade from 0.12 to 0.13 but this command does not exist for 0.14? Is there any reason? I read it's recommended to upgrade one major version in a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Terraform team publishes [upgrade guides](https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/index.html) for each major version. As you mentioned, the only documented and supported upgrade path is to move one major version at a time: v0.12 to v0.13, v0.13 to v0.14, and then v0.14 to the forthcoming v0.15 (which is currently in beta at the time I'm writing this).

There is only an automatic upgrade command if there's something to automatically upgrade; that was true for v0.11 to v0.12 and for v0.12 to v0.13, but those were particularly complex examples of an upgrade process (significant changes to the configuration language) and not something that is typical for all Terraform CLI upgrades.

Comment: thanks, so if I understand correctly the upgrade from 0.12 to 0.13 will be harder/take more time than from 0.13 to 0.14?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really say for certain because I don't know which Terraform features you are using and thus which of the upgrade guide sections will be relevant to you, but I think it's fair to say that the changes in v0.14 are primarily related to features outside of the Terraform language and therefore Terraform is able to handle more of the upgrade process automatically itself, in most cases without a need to modify your existing Terraform modules.